# Setting fonts on controls that do not support a font

Tags: c#, compact-framework

Using the CF 2.0 here. In order to support multiple languages, I set the font on each control (using a recursive function) when the form is created. I've found that some controls simply do not support a font property, so code like this:

```
cntrl.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 12.0f, FontStyle.Regular);
```

throws the NotSupportedException exception. Even calling:

```
if (cntrl.Font != null)
```

throws the same exception. To get around this, I've written a helper function as follows:

```
private static bool DoesControlSupportFont(Control cntrl)
{
    // Some control's do not support the Font property
    bool bSupported = true;
    if ((cntrl is HScrollBar) ||
        (cntrl is Panel) ||
        (cntrl is PictureBox) ||
        (cntrl is ProgressBar) ||
        (cntrl is TrackBar) ||
        (cntrl is VScrollBar))
        bSupported = false;

    return bSupported;
}
```

This works but seems inefficient and a little inelegant. Is this the recommended way to deal with controls that do not support a font? Perhaps there's a more efficient way (like using a try-catch block and dealing with the exception)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are other viable options to solve this issue than the ones you have already mentioned.

In the full framework, you can test for the `[Browsable(false)]` attribute, to get an *indication* of what you are intended to use. This information has been stripped from the Compact Framework assemblies.

If I were you I'd at least put your existing code in a try/catch block, specifically catching `NotSupportedException`, so future controls are automatically covered (anyone can subclass `Control`).

I would leave in the hardcoded checks too as these cases aren't exactly exceptional.

PS. Ran into [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bluecollar/archive/2007/02/08/adding-compact-framework-design-time-attributes-or-more-fun-with-textboxes.aspx) a while ago, explaining how to "hide" properties from the CF designer.

Comment: OK, thanks. Good to have a second opinion on this and the link was an eye-opener. Although one doesn't tend to do much design-time work in CF, its good to know adding properties can be done.